# Está OK editar uma pergunta só para ter mais visibilidade?

Tags: debate, edição, proposta-para-faq

Tenho percebido que o horário em que uma pergunta é feita influencia bastante na quantidade de respostas e *upvotes*, por causa da visibilidade na página inicial.

Às vezes acabamos fazendo uma pergunta em um "horário ruim" e ela obtêm pouca atenção. Então vamos lá e fazemos aquela "ediçãozinha básica", que não agrega nada de bom, só pra obter mais visibilidade. (E isso funciona!).

Isso é aceitável/recomendável?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Perguntas são feitas para serem vistas**, não é mesmo?

Não tem problema editar de vez em quando para chamar a atenção para uma pergunta ou resposta. Idealmente, a edição deve melhorar a pergunta. Mesmo que não seja uma grande edição, sempre há algo que pode ser melhorado.

E, claro, não vale abusar: não edite a pergunta todo dia, muito menos várias vezes por dia, só para chamar a atenção.

Comment: "não edite a pergunta todo dia, muito menos várias vezes por dia" mesmo porque [após 10 edições a pergunta automaticamente vira wiki da comunidade...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79697/177950) :P

Comment: Não vira mais, @mgibsonbr: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/

Comment: Hehe eu me lembrava de um caso aqui mesmo no SOpt onde isso aconteceu, então achava que ainda era assim. Mas essa mudança foi recente, não estava ciente dela. Depois vou ler o post com calma, pra saber mais sobre as mudanças.

Comment: Posso perguntar o que é o Wiki da Comunidade? É tipo um site à parte onde se pode postar listar as melhores perguntas ou respostas ou algo assim/

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Não, é um tipo de postagem no site cuja intenção é ser uma construção coletiva. Veja o link que postei no comentário acima (em inglês).

Answer (score 9):

Editar perguntas (e respostas) é a forma menos poluída dos infames *bumps* que se têm em fóruns de discussão.

Mas depende de pessoa pra pessoa, também. Eu não sou contra porque sou um perfeccionista chato de galocha. Quando respondo, nem sempre acerto as palavras ou a gramática e quando estou de bobeira e vou rever o que escrevi sempre pego um errinho aqui e outro ali.

Mas eu acho que se fosse possível enviar os tópicos demasiadamente editados para fila de análise, mesmo que o revisor já tenha plenos poderes para editar livremente, poderia diminuir *bumps* em quantidades exageradas, afinal sempre tem aquele que encontra 10 problemas e corrige um por hora só pra forçar a barra.

Comment: Posts com mais de 10 edições são automaticamente sinalizados, justamente para prevenir abusos.

Comment: Legal saber disso :)