# Edições de postagem (perguntas/respostas) antigas e já resolvidas há anos

Tags: debate, edição

Ultimamente tenho visto muitas alterações de perguntas e respostas que já foram respondidas e possuem uma resposta aceita há anos, muitas das vezes as alterações são modificações simples de apenas uma letra, o que dá a impressão de que só foi alterada para ser lançada no topo da página Home em busca de votos.

Minhas dúvidas:

- Isso contribui para alguma coisa no site?
- Tem alguma regra para alteração?

Como solicitado segue algumas alterações feitas em um espaço de tempo muito curto e com simples alterações.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/158717/revisions às 11:06
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165499/revisions às 11:36
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165932/revisions às 12:27
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164518/revisions às 12:51
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164708/revisions às 12:56
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164809/revisions às 13:11
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165105/revisions às 13:20

Sei perfeitamente que alterações podem serem feitas e que isso é bom, como já fui orientado pelo próprio moderado das alterações, mas que sejam feitas de forma mais espaçadas e que seja feita de modo que não precise de tantas alterações futuras.

Não sei o que isso ajuda:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165105/revisions

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muitas dessas alterações poderiam ter sido feitas de uma única vez como me orientaram.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116209/discussion-on-question-by-marconcilio-souza-edicoes-de-postagem-perguntas-respo)

Comment: Tentei elaborar uma resposta, mas o ítem 2 realmente fica impossível sem saber a que se refere exatamente, e o 1 muito vago. Li o chat depois, e percebi que não foi só impressão minha. Seria o caso de [edit] para apontar casos concretos, e quais os problemas notados. Vale notar que o "Topo da Home" não é para "coisas relevantes" e sim para que a comunidade possa ver tudo que foi acrescido ou alterado no site, efetivamente aumentando a participação Por isso edições em massa não são recomendadas, acaba atrapalhando o conteúdo orgânico - edits avulsos já não atrapalham.

Comment: @Bacco, feito , não quero confusão, só estou cobrando uma coisa que já me foi cobrado aqui.

Comment: Ah, é direcionado à mesma pessoa. Isso esclarece bastante as coisas, junto de outros ítens que analisei (são estatísticas que mod tem acesso, e como não estão no tópico da pergunta vou tratar em outro momento). Faltou você explicar qual o problema específico que viu em cada um deles, caso não tenha entendido a razão da edição, mas de qq forma, reabri o post.

Comment: Ainda: creio que é bom você analisar edições pelo modo markdown. Por exemplo, essa menção do post 165105 foi uma atualização de link. No seu print isso não aparece.  Ainda, não sei se você não acompanhou, mas o engine de markdown da rede mudou. Inclusive no que diz respeito a uso de espaços. Outro exemplo: [meu edit no seu post acrescentou só espaços](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8497/5). Só que isso mudou completamente a apresentação das quebras de linha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou citar link por link:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/158717/revisions às 11:06: O autor corrigiu o markdown.
2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165499/revisions às 11:36: O autor colocou o `/join`, que é para quem usa o repl.it logado. Na verdade provavelmente foi um engano dele, eu também me enganei, esse `/join` não funciona para quem não está logado, é culpa do `repl.it` que nos faz pensar que isso se trata de um "compartilhar" (os textos deles são confusos às vezes). A intenção do autor me parece apenas que foi usar o link "certo" (mesmo que cometendo um equivoco, assim como eu fiz também outro dia).
3. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165932/revisions às 12:27: Corrigiu o português, eu também tenho problemas com vírgulas e às vezes confundo tempos verbais, nunca foi o meu forte, uns colegas vivem me chamando a atenção devido minhas gafes.
4. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164518/revisions às 12:51: Os links da documentação da Microsoft estão mudando e o autor já esta se adiantando para caso os links antigos "morram".
5. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164708/revisions às 12:56: Corrigiu o markdown e ajustou o "gênero" da palavra.
6. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/164809/revisions às 13:11: Mesmo do segundo link, sobre um problema de entendimento no repl.it (compartilhamento).
7. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/165105/revisions às 13:20: Mesmo do quarto link, sobre a documentação da Microsoft.

A imagem que citou (print) também é sobre o link, é culpa do repl.it que também me confundiu, fazendo pensar que esse era o link correto para compartilhamento em outros sites, não é culpa do autor.

Eu vou resumir tudo o que penso disso, acho que deve analisar postagem por postagem, independente de fazer diversas edições aparentemente simples por dia, não é porque fez muitas que significa que não tem motivação real, das que citou nenhuma foi para fazer o "bump", foram para ajustes razoáveis (mesmo que os do `repl.it` tenha sido um engano).

De resto cabe o que eu [já disse no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56150536#56150536):

> Acho que esse assunto já foi bastante discutido e até definido pela comunidade [Está OK editar uma pergunta só para ter mais visibilidade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1926/3635) e [Perguntas antigas podem ser postadas novamente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3966/3635). Teria algum ponto além do já debatido que você acha que difere bastante para valer debatermos novamente o assunto?

Acho que esses dois links já orientam bastante sobre motivações e sobre a utilidade do "bump", se o conteúdo é interessante não há mal algum em colocar em evidencia novamente, e nenhuma das postagens parece que foi feita mais de uma vez em períodos curtos, não acho que ficar trazendo mais links sobre revisões que acredita serem abusivas vai adiantar, analise por si só e com bastante atenção, *todos usuários tem alguma autonomia*, vai notar que provavelmente são bem mais do que "bumps" e outros serão bumps, mas não serão abusivos.

E se por acaso encontrar algum uso disso de qualquer usuário, seja veterano, novato ou moderador, **sinalize**, mas tenha total certeza que realmente existe abuso.